# Rename all files on directory with pattern [Powershell]

Tags: powershell

I have some troubles with Windows OneDrive and very much files on my OS renamed like from:

```
index.js
```

to:

```
index-DESKTOP-9T6I5F5.js
```

How can i remove that pattern from all files in directory with help cmd/powershell?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
param(
    $targetPath = "d:\tmp",
    $pattern = "-DESKTOP-9T6I5F5"
)

Get-ChildItem $targetPath -Recurse -File | ForEach-Object {
    Rename-Item $_.FullName -NewName ($_ -replace $pattern) -WhatIf
}
```

test it and than remove -WhatIf

Comment: Should i to enter this to powershelll or create some file with this text ?

Comment: no difference, you can just copy it to the console

Comment: Could this be updated with a `$replacement` parameter if you wanted to do a find and replace for a pattern?

Answer (score 0):

Depending on what part of the filename you want to remove of course, but if I understand the question properly, you want everything after the first hyphen to be removed.
You can do this like:

```
Get-ChildItem -Path '<root folder where the files are>' -Filter '*.js' -File -Recurse | 
Rename-Item -NewName { $_.BaseName.Split("-")[0], $_.Extension } -WhatIf
```

Remove the `-WhatIf` safety switch if you are satisfied with what is displayed in the console is correct.